# Vanishing of Tor group at every fiber implies flatness

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, derived-categories

I have some question on a proof in Huybrechts' "Fourier-Mukai Transfomation in Algebraic Geometry".

Let $ f \colon S \to X$ be a morphism between Noetherian schemes, and we denote by $i_x \colon S_x \to S$ the canonical morphism from the fiber $S_x$ to $S$ (here $x \in X$).

> #### Lemma.3.31
>
> Suppose $\mathcal{Q} \in \text{D}^b(S)$ and assume that for all closed point $x \in X$ the derived pullback $Li_x^* \mathcal{Q}$ is concentrated in degree zero, i.e. isomorphic to a sheaf. Then $\mathcal{Q}$ isomorphic to a sheaf on $S$ which is flat on $X$.

There is a following argument in its proof.

> $\mathcal{H}^{-1}(Li_x^*(\mathcal{H}^0(\mathcal{Q}))=0$ for any closed point $x \in X$, and this shows that $\mathcal{H}^0(\mathcal{Q})$ is flat over $X$.

(Notation: $Li_x^*$ is the derived inverse image and $\mathcal{H}^{-1}$ is th $-1$-th cohomology sheaf.)

#### My question

How to verify this argument?

i.e.

How to prove the next proposition?:

If $\mathcal{F}$ is a coherent sheaf on $S$ such that $\mathcal{H}^{-1}(Li_x^*(\mathcal{F}))=0$ for any closed point $x \in X$, then $\mathcal{F}$ is flat over $X$.

#### My attempt

We have to prove that for any $s \in S$, $\mathcal{F}_s$ is flat over $\mathcal{O}_{X,f(s)}$.

Firstly, I tried to deal with  an affine case. Let $S=\operatorname{Spec} B$ , $X= \operatorname{Spec}A$, $s= \mathfrak{q} \in S$, and $\mathcal{F}=\tilde{M}$ be a sheaf associated to a finitely generated $B$ module. In addition, I assumed $\mathfrak{m}=f(s) \in X$  to be a maximal ideal (equivalently, closed point), so that I can use the assumption $\mathcal{H}^{-1}(Li_x^*(\mathcal{F}))=0$ for closed point $x$.

Then $\mathcal{H}^{-1}(Li_x^*(\mathcal{F}))=0$ is equivelent to $\text{Tor}_1^B(B \otimes_A A/\mathfrak{m}, M)=0$, and we obtain $\text{Tor}_1^{B_\mathfrak{q}}(B_\mathfrak{q}/\mathfrak{m}B_\mathfrak{q}, M_\mathfrak{q})=0$ by localization. Now we want to prove $\text{Tor}_1^{A_\mathfrak{m}}(A_\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}A_\mathfrak{m}, M_\mathfrak{q})=0$ , since it implies that $M_\mathfrak{q}$ is flat over $A_\mathfrak{m}$. But I have no idea how to conclude it from $\text{Tor}_1^{B_\mathfrak{q}}(B_\mathfrak{q}/\mathfrak{m}B_\mathfrak{q}, M_\mathfrak{q})=0$.

Thank you for your any help!

Comment: There are typos in the statement of the lemma

Comment: 1. Please use \operatorname{Spec} to format $\operatorname{Spec}$: it produces better spacing. I've upgraded your post with this change. 2. I agree with Maxime Ramzi: you should have some $S$ in the statement of your lemma, but you don't. Please check this and see whether it changes your attempt. 3. I think I remember a question very similar to this one which was asked around early/mid December 2019, but I cannot find it via search at this time (I checked somewhat thoroughly).

Comment: Thank you guys, I have fixed it.

Comment: I'm not sure if you've seen this, but the paragraph immediately following the claim you're trying to prove has a sketch of the proof. It uses the fact that if $A \to B$ is a local ring homomorphism, and $M$ a $B$-module, then $M$ is $A$-flat if for any ideal $\mathfrak{a} \subset A$, the map $\mathfrak{a} \otimes M \to M$ is injective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I happened to meet this lemma in [a work by Bridgeland](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9809114). There is an erratum for the statement which says that we need to assume $f$ to be flat (see the footnote for Lemma 4.3).